# React Router JWT protect routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app on top of laravel in which I have a custom login screen using jwt auth. I get a token set in local storage but I am trying to protect and redirect routes if not logged in. The problem is checking the token before rendering the route. Everything I have tried, I end up in a huge loop. Please help. Here is my app.jsx

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Login from './components/auth/login';
import Header from './components/header/';
import store from './store';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { PropsRoute, PublicRoute, PrivateRoute } from 'react-router-with-props';


let getToken = () =>{

  var auth = false;
  var token = localStorage.getItem('toobiauth')

  if(token){
    var tokenExpiration = jwtDecode(token).exp;
    var dateNow = new Date();

    if(tokenExpiration < dateNow.getTime()/1000){
        auth = false
    }else{
        auth = true
    }
  }else{
    auth = false
  }
  return auth;

}


ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
       <Router>
         <Header>
           <Switch> 
             <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
             <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
             <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" authed={getToken()} redirectTo="/login" component={Dashboard}/>
           </Switch>
           </Header>
       </Router>
    </Provider>
   ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

And here is my login

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch, connect } from "react-redux";
import Submit from '../ui/buttons/submit';
import Textfield from '../ui/inputs/textfield';
import {loginUser} from '../../actions/authactions';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';


function login(props) {

    const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

    const submitLogin = () =>{
        props.dispatch(loginUser(username, password))
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        var token = localStorage.getItem('toobiauth')

        if(token){
            var tokenExpiration = jwtDecode(token).exp;
            var dateNow = new Date();

            if(tokenExpiration < dateNow.getTime()/1000){
                console.log('expired');
            }else{
                props.history.push('/dashboard')
                console.log('login screen')
            }
        }

    },[auth]);


    return <div className="page_wrapper">
        <Textfield type="text" change={setUsername}/>
        <Textfield type="password" change={setPassword}/>
        <Submit action={submitLogin} width={'100%'}/>
    </div>;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
      app: state.app,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(login);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define your own PrivateRoute.jsx, in that component you can check if user authenticated then allow user to route protected route else redirect user to login route

***PrivateRoute.jsx***

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null)  
  useEffect(() => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('toobiauth')
        if(token){
            let tokenExpiration = jwtDecode(token).exp;
            let dateNow = new Date();

            if(tokenExpiration < dateNow.getTime()/1000){
                setIsAuthenticated(false)
            }else{
                setIsAuthenticated(true)
            }
        } else {
           setIsAuthenticated(false)
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [auth])

  if(isAuthenticated === null){
    return <></>
  }

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated ? (
        <Redirect to='/login'/>
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

***App.js***

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Login from './components/auth/login';
import Header from './components/header/';
import store from './store';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';
// import new PrivateRoute component defined in codeblock above
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
       <Router>
         <Header>
           <Switch> 
             <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
             <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
             <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
           </Switch>
           </Header>
       </Router>
    </Provider>
   ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: will it reach private route `path="/"` in presence of public route of same path above?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, it should be **<PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />**

Comment: thanks! i ended up doing this with a class component but pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @onuriltan. will this protest all kind of routes ? like `/**` or `/app/services/**` ? so we dont need to write any logic to check session in any other componenet ?

Comment: @Rookie007 `all kind of routes` you mean api routes or frontend url paths(routes)?

Comment: @onuriltan I meant front end UI paths, anyway we can protect backend API paths with token in header,

Comment: Is it enough to use jwtDecode to check if the jwt is expired? Is it not necessary to validate the token server side? @TylerNichol

Comment: @ericgithinji I think it depends on your architectural decision, so if you are using jwt token then you can easily check on frontend if its expired so you don't have to use backend for it, but frontend date time can vary depends on where user using the app, so a second check with backend is better. But you can always convert current user date with global date and then compare in the frontend.

Comment: @onuriltan Okay thanks. I'm wondering from a security point of view: since we're not validating the token's signature server side, what would prevent a malicious actor from generating a jwt with an 'exp' field in its payload and setting it to a value that would pass the above test? Wouldn't this allow the person to access the restricted routes? Or is this a very minimal risk because they would need to know exactly what our code checks for?

Comment: @ericgithinji Good point, I think in that case yes user can reach restricted routes, but I believe from server side the request validation will fail since the token is not encoded with correct private key which should be held in our server only, so user will see http errors but yes they will see restricted routes without data in that case, so better to check with server if token is expired or not